# Automate VMware to switch to full screen VM after host boots

Tags: windows-7, boot, automation, vmware-workstation

What I want to be able to do is boot up my Windows 7 laptop, have VMware Workstation automatically load and once that's loaded have it automatically boot one particular VM and have it automatically go into full screen mode (or dual screen if it detects two monitors).

The end result would be that I could (for the most part) ignore my host OS and just "boot" directly into my virtual machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this of any use to you?

The long of short of it is to create a new VMWare shortcut, point it to the VMX of your choice using the -X switch which should launch your required guest as full screen:

http://www.petri.co.il/forums/showpost.php?p=107879&postcount=3